# Visual Studio Publishing Bootstrap.Js as Encrypted

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, encryption

For some reason everytime I publish either the bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js it gets published as an encrypted file.

I'm running VS2013 with bootstrap 3.0.2 and I have decrypted the files on my computer. I have restarted the program re-pulled in the files.

Its really annoying as every time I want to publish the website I have remember to remove the encryption or nobody can access the site.

Comment: You don't need to include Bootstrap as part of your project... I know it's not really a solution, but rather a workaround, but you can reference Bootstrap from a CDN (http://www.bootstrapcdn.com in case you were wondering).

Answer (score 1):

Use these line of code instead of using file :

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```